# Differences in log answers

Tags: r

I trying to attempt a log-log plot in R, but when I take the log of a particular value I do not get consistent answers, for example:

```
In R:
> log(192.4)
[1] 5.259577

On my phone:
2.28

On a web scientific calculator
I get: 2.2842050677018
```

What causes the inconsistencies between R and the other calculators? Which one would be the correct to use?

[Scientific calculator](http://web2.0calc.com/) i used.

Comment: You should have used `log10(192.4)` to get the answer 2.28.

Comment: Which one is "correct" depends on your application.  If you just want to draw a log-log plot, it probably doesn't matter; the plot will appear the same, but the axes will be scaled differently.  `log10` will be more interpretable if you're not used to natural (base-e) logarithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In common with many other programming languages, R calculates the natural logarithm, i.e. using base `e` with the function `log()`. If you want the base 10 logarithm, you need to use `log10()`:

```
log(192.4)
[1] 5.259577


log10(192.4)
[1] 2.284205
```

This, and more, is documented in the help for `?log`

Comment: d'oh should of seen this coming